# unable to keep an element inside parent element

Tags: html, css

Using CSS, how can I keep an element inside its parent element. I have created a DIV & placed an HR tag inside it along with two combobox.

The HR tag is going outside the DIV. Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mgqLoLt/).

```
<div style="width:70%; border:solid">
  <hr style="position:absolute;width:100%;z-index:-1;" /> Option One
  <select style="margin-right:50px">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>

  </select>
  <span></span> Option Two
  <select>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Style:

```
h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
}

h2 span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-color: #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative`to the parent div. Position absolute is relative to the document unless inside an element that has relative positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the new code: - I added `position:relative` to the container, which means to contain all absolute positioned child items.

```
<div style="width:70%; border:solid;position:relative">
  <hr style="position:absolute;width:100%;z-index:-1;" /> Option One
  <select style="margin-right:50px">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
  </select>
  <span></span> Option Two
  <select>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
  </select>
</div>
```